# Need a list of TFS versions (numbers) and their mapping to TFS 2019 updates

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

Our installed version is 17.143.28621.4 (2019 on premise).
The team that installed it is not sure which update was downloaded.
I [checked the latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019?view=azure-devops)
and cannot find version 17.143.28621.4 in the available downloads.

Could not find any page with version/description mapping.

Answer (score 5):

That's the 2019.0 RTW release.

[image]

[The build number table is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline#server-build-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a full version list of TFS and Azure DevOps, please find it here: https://github.com/FokkoVeegens/AzureDevOpsServerVersions. Jesse already pointed you to the right version.